# Check if an element copy exists in the document

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am parsing the document for some elements(specifically anchor tags) and then pushing them into an array. When new elements are added to the page via ajax I run my parser again to collect my elements and push them to my array again.

Problem I am facing is, I want to delete the elements from my array when they are removed from the page, I do not have any unique ids for these elements, they are mere anchor tags. Is there a unique element id attached to the jQuery object of the element? If so, I can push a copy jQuery object to my array instead of standard JS object.

This is not a "check if element exists on page" question. I have a copy of the element, and I want to check if the original elements still exists on page or not, I hope you see the difference between the two questions.

Comment: Aren't there any else property attached to anchor tags, so that you can differentiate between them?

Comment: So basically, the question is how to differ between the original elements to the copied elements? After adding them, they are part of the DOM so unless they have a different attribute (like `class` or `data-copy=true`) I can't think on an alternative solution.

Comment: @NitinVarpe nope, they are all simple anchor tags with hrefs, they might even have same hrefs but I need to treat them as different elements since they can appear multiple times on page.

Comment: But when you add those copied elements to the DOM, can't you do add them another attribute? Something like: `.attr('data-copied','true');` ?

Comment: @OfirBaruch Lets say there are 3 anchor tags(2 identical and 1 different) on page, I parse them, now I have a copy of those 3 anchor tags in my array. Now lets say one of the anchor tag got deleted from the page due to some operation. Now I want to write a method to check if elements in my array are still existent on the page or not, in this case one anchor tag doesn't exist anymore, so I aim to recognize which one of these 3 elements got deleted and want to delete it from my collection.

Comment: @OfirBaruch The only way I can think of right now is to add a data-id to each of the element parsed my me and store a unique random number in it. So when I want to run a clean up on my array, I can just check if the $([data-id=XXX]) exists on page. Unless there is a better way, I will have to implement it like this. (I dont want to modify all the elements that I parse, there are going to be thousands of them)

Comment: I'm afraid that there's no other option since there's nothing to make those elements unique, there's no a `built-in` id for every element in the DOM (as far as I know).

Comment: @OfirBaruch In that case I think i'm left with no other option. Thanks!

Comment: @Rao Your idea to add an identifier to the duplicated elements is the way I would go.  Add `data-id=new Date().getTime()` to each element before you duplicate it (if it doesn't already have that attribute).  That's a nice and easy way to implement what you need.